# Hedgehog cold and lethargic, what to do?

Tags: health, hedgehog

I gave a neighbor kid a ride and she forgot her hedgehog and left it in my car. It was about 35 degrees Fahrenheit last night, and is now around 50.

The hedgehog has been in the car, parked outside, from 11:00 pm last night until just now at 3:45. She's lethargic, like in torpor, but I only just barely touched her, and set the cage in a warm place.

What should I do or what signs should I look for and what should I not do?

Comment: Call a vet, don't really on the internet to save a life in an emergency.

Comment: Thanks, what the heck am I thinking? I'm calling right now!

Answer (score 8):

I called an Emergency veterinary hospital and asked what should be done. They said to put a hot water bottle wrapped in a towel next to the hedgehog, which I had already done. After about two hours the hedgehog appeared to be OK, and I was able to get a hold of the owner, and took it to them. The next day the owner reported that it was "fine".
Since I read on the website below that hedgehogs hibernate and enter torpor, I was not nearly as worried as I was when I discovered it in my un-heated car. Of course, I doubt it would be good to let this happen often, but no harm done this time.
And I would like to thank James Jenkins for pulling my head of my you-know-what. Calling the vet should be the FIRST thing anyone does if they think they have an emergency!
hedgehogstreet.org/about-hedgehogs/hibernation